# Updated from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Wubi to 13.10, won't boot now

Tags: updates, wubi

Yesterday night, I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS through Wubi, since I don't want it to be on a CD or a USB. Later that night, I have updated the version from 12.04 LTS to 13.10. It asked me to reboot to complete the installation of the update, so I did that.

Afterwards, like normal booting, it asked me which OS do I want to open. Windows 7 or Ubuntu, so I chose Ubuntu, of course, but, after I clicked on the Ubuntu button, the Ubuntu start up screen shows (the Ubuntu logo which has five grey loading dots under it) and then it disappears and turns into a black screen with a white line. The white line isn't even moving. What's going on? Please help.

Comment: Also, you should [convert Wubi install into regular install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) before doing update since Wubi isn't supported since 12.04

Answer (score -1):

What I always do in a problem is to reinstall whatever version of Ubuntu I am using. That usually fixes the problem (Do not get into any partitioning or any complicated stuff while installing. That may cause problems while booting). Cheers! :)

Comment: Do I really have to uninstall Ubuntu from my laptop now? Isn't there another way to fix that problem?

Comment: I don't know any other way to fix this one... Sorry.. But you can still browse through other questions and look for other options...