# Problem in installing Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, wubi, system-installation

I have downloaded the link provided in home page of Ubuntu i.e., [12.04 for desktop ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts). I got downloaded a file which of size 733 MB in ISO format and then I extract files from the ISO image and then I click on the Wubi and it re-directed me into a link and took me an 30 mins or so.

After completing the download, installation came to halt throwing some log error. It happened 2 times for me. Is there anything problem with my process with my installation process or is there any other process for installing? Currently I'm using Windows 8 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu from Windows 8. Help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The general recommendations I can give: _do not use Wubi_!!! It is discontinued since 13.04, so you will have to [convert existing installation to regular](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) before you can upgrade further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm not burning ISO image into a CD. I'm extracting files using WinRAR. Is that okay ??

Comment: I never used Wubi. It is _better_ to write ISO to CD rather then extracting it, because regular installation of Ubuntu has some advantages over Wubi.

Comment: Where can I get links of them other than Wubi ??

Comment: Did you look into [suggested solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)?

Comment: Also, there is a [guide specially for Windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: how are you installing Ubuntu? USB? CD? i recommend either of these methods, i use both depending on the age of the computer I'm installing too. if you are using either of these options what is the error that the installer is giving you?

Comment: "installation came to halt throwing some log error" Without knowing *what* the error said, it's unlikely anyone could suggest a specific solution, but as Danatela says, [that question may help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

Answer (score 1):

(Everything I have read about Wubi indicates you should not use it!)
I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, downloaded the file and burned to a DVD.
You can run Ubuntu from the DVD so you can try it out without installing it.
If you choose to install it is pretty easy, try dual-boot (mine is with XP).
There is a partition manager in the install program, I set my partitions about half & half between Ubuntu and XP. After installation a new bootup screen will appear which will allow you to boot either operating system. My XP still works fine, no problems.

My total installation time was around 2 hours including downloading Ubuntu and burning the DVD.

After that I spent HOURS checking out Ubuntu! There are a lot of programs included.
It recognized my network immediately and I was online doing email in minutes.
Also downloaded pics from my phone right away.

Good luck, you can do it!

Answer (score 1):

The general instruction you should follow: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Instruction for Windows 8 64-bit UEFI: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Also, there is a special [tag for dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Just read those instructions.

[Do not use Wubi](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice). It's not designed for Windows 8 and it's support [discontinued after 13.04 Release](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-downloader-for-windows-discontinued-from-ubuntu-13-04.html)