# Disk Space Issues

Tags: disk-usage

I have total  70 GB in drive from 160 GB of hard drive in which ubuntu is installed
and in that drive 20 GB is free space, still ubuntu keep giving me pop up that not enough free space.

Here is the output of `df -H`

```
Filesystem  Size  Used   Avail  Use%  Mounted on 
/dev/loop0  10G   9.3G   193M   98%   / 
udev        1.6G  4.1k   1.6G   1%    /dev
tmpfs       315M  930k   314M   1%    /run
none        5.3M  0      5.3M   0%    /run/lock
none        1.6G  365k   1.6G   1%    /run/shm
/dev/sda6   81G   59G    22G    74%   /host
```

How to get that solved?

Comment: Please provide results of `df -H` (and you talk about disc size but the notice is about a full -partition-).

Comment: And there is your problem: `/dev/loop0  10G   9.3G   193M   98%   /` Oh and this is not a normal Ubuntu. Is this wubi? Or virtual?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running a Wubi system, which is not recommended. You haven't installed Ubuntu to your harddisk. Instead, you have a file that is stored on a Windows file system that is used to create a virtual harddisk. That file is 10GB large and is almost full. How much free space you have on the real disk is irrelevant. Windows can damage a Wubi install if you get a power outage or something like that, so it really isn't as dependable as proper Ubuntu installed on your disk.

You could resize that file and then expand the file system, but I would rather recommend that you install Ubuntu properly. It is easier and will give you much better results. If you copy your home directory from the Wubi install and to your proper install, you'll keep all your personal settings and data.

If you want to resize your Wubi virtual disk, I would recommend that you open a new question for that.

Comment: The following link may be helpful: [How to convert WUBI install into regular install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)