# Will the Ubuntu replace my Windows?

Tags: system-installation, windows

I'm going to install Ubuntu with Windows installer. If I choose `C:\` for the drive installation, will the Ubuntu replace my windows?

I installed my Windows on drive `C:\`.
Thank you...

Comment: wubi will not replace Windows. However, it is not supported for the latest versions of Ubuntu, and is fairly buggy. You may be better off using a virtual machine or dual booting.

Comment: I agree with @Dillmo. You shouldn't use Wubi. Boot from the Ubuntu DVD/bootstick, and then select *Install Ubuntu* and then *Install alongside with Windows*

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Wubi, it should be easy and not touch existing Windows installation. However, using Wubi is not recommended. It has cons in performance, has no ability to hibernate and it has unsupported releases. I suggest you to [move to alongside install](https://askubuntu.com/q/635/171636) when you are ready.