# Remove Ubuntu installed by wubi to install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

I currently have Windows 7 installed on a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed via Wubi. So when I boot up I have the option to load up either WIndows or Ubuntu. I am going to install just 14.04 on its own as my current (wubi) version is made up of lots of previous versions added on top of each other.

So I am going to back up my Home folder, put the bookable usb stick in with Ubuntu 14.04 on it and click the option to install alongside windows, during the install.

My question is will I need to remove the wubi version of Ubuntu, that I currently have or can I install the new Ubuntu (alongside Windows) and then remove the wubi version when I know all is OK?

Comment: No reason to uninstall unless you need the space to make room for the new one. It's better to just [convert the install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) - unless there's some specific reason you want a fresh one.

Answer (score 1):

Well after a bit of time searching and a bit of help from others along the way, I decided to remove the old version and install a fresh copy. I took everything that I wanted off the wubi install and then um-installed it in Windows. I then installed the latest version via the USB and opted to install alongside Windows. It took a bit of time to get Ubuntu back to how I wanted it, but it is there now. It is true that I could keep the old wubi version there, but for me this was a good opportunity to have a fresh copy.

Comment: It is better this way. It gets easier to do fresh installs if you so desire